# Jacobi and Legendre Symbol

Tags: number-theory, quadratic-residues

I'm trying to calculate the value of $k=(\frac{5}{645784635653487634537})$, that is either: $1,-1$ or $0$.  (Jacobi/Legendre symbol)

Since $\gcd(5,645784635653487634537)=1$,  we  know that $k$ is either $1$ or $-1$.

Now, how can I calculate the value of $k$ with such big denominator? Congruences are impossible to do with such values.

Comment: The quadratic reciprocity theorem ought to make short shrift of this one. Do you not know it? Is something preventing you from applying it? Note that 645784635653487634537 is prime.

Comment: Or is showing 645784635653487634537 is prime the part you're stuck on?

Comment: Yeah, note that it is prime. Its so obvious.  I mean, why are you having trouble computing jacobi symbols with primality is just so trivially apparent?  How else can we posture and express intelligence to satiate our egos at your expense, without actually answering the question at hand?  When in doubt, just call the answer obvious and mock the questioner for asking.  math.stackexchange 101

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the $6$th property of Jacobi symbol here : [WIKI PAGE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobi_symbol#Properties). You don't need to prove that $645784635653487634537$ is prime. You just need to notice that $645784635653487634537$ and $5$ are coprime and odd. Since $5$ is prime you only need to prove that $5$ does not divide $645784635653487634537$ which is obvious because this big number does not end with $5$.

We can conclude the same way than the other answer.

Answer (score 1):

645784635653487634537 is prime, so we can apply the [Quadratic reciprocity law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_reciprocity):

$k\cdot(\frac{645784635653487634537}{5}) = -1^{\frac{5 - 1}{2} \cdot \frac{645784635653487634537 - 1}{2}}=1$.

Now $(\frac{645784635653487634537}{5}) = (\frac{2}{5}) = -1$, so $k=-1$.